# django url error in html href

Tags: python, django, url, href

I followed the official site Django and now I'm developing a new site based in Django.

My schema is:

/Home
/----Charts

My home template have this code:

```
{%  for option in menu.options %}

    <li ><a href="{% url  option.link %}"><i class='{{ option.class }}'></i><span></span>{{option.name}}</a> </li>

{% endfor %}
```

Menu is a dict:

```
self.menu = {
        "options": [
            {
                "link": "",
                "name": "Home",
                "class": "icon-dashboard",

            },

            {
                "link": "charts:charts",
                "name": "Charts",
                "class": "icon-bar-chart",
            }
        ]
```

But I don't know why didn't work this " {% url  option.link %} "

Home/urls.py:

```
 url(r'^$', views.Home.as_view(), name='Home'),

url(r'^charts/', include('charts.urls',namespace="charts")),
```

Charts/urls.py

```
url(r'^$', views.IndexCharts.as_view(), name='charts'),
```

I'm doing well or something is wrong? If I type hardcode {% url 'charts:charts' %} it works.

The error is: Exception Value:
Reverse for 'option.link' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Sorry about my poor english.

Thx a lot.

Comment: Have you tried using the [reverse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) function when making your menu dictionary? Instead of assigning link to 'charts:charts', assign it to the reverse of the url.

Comment: Well sorry Django verify if all urls exists in the urlsconf I think.( some option.link got a nonexistent url) Sorry if some mod can delete the questions... Thanks.

Comment: You can delete your own question, if you like